# Clear BIOS "PCI auto configuration"

Tags: configuration, hp-proliant, bios, pci-express

I got a new **HP ProLiant dl360p G8** server. I bought an **SFP module** from amazon that was made for HP servers. When I turn the server on, the link light stays lite until the BIOS makes it to PCI auto configuration start, and then the light goes out and the OS says "**disconnected**".

I contacted the manufacturer and they stated it is due to the auto configuration and that it can be cleared.

I have updated the **FlexFabric card firmware,** I have updated all firmware I could find (except BIOS since I don't have warranty), reset the BIOS multiple ways, and googled it like crazy.

How can I clear this config? Or can you point me in the right direction at least?